# Getting radio button selected value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How can I get the radio button clicked value?

Actually I need a custom filter for gender which I selected in my `<form>`. From the output I need to filter with gender. My `filter` and `orderBy` in `ng-repeat` is not working properly.

Here is a link to my Plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/7ZBcMDrJzSreD73R9aNq?p=preview

```
for(var i=0;i<$scope.details.length;i++) {

    if($scope.details[i]===$scope.options[i])
        $scope.details=myService.getForm($scope.user);

}
```

Comment: take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Plunker given the value from the Gender is getting within the `$scope.user`

```
 $scope.submitTheForm=function(){
    myService.setForm($scope.user);
    $scope.user={};
};
```

Check this **[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nm0ZXqy70jitZFLV8j05?p=preview)**

Comment: I am getting the value of radio button in the form code. I am asking about the radio buttons which i need to put in the output form file for filtering data based on gender selection. if selected value print the data with that gender only.

Comment: what's the use of defining two separate directive (`<form-ajs></form-ajs>`), since both are linked each other you can include within one single directive

Comment: As I need to make use of a service I created 2 directives

Comment: Next I need to put filters and sort on my output. Gender filter ..so I need to know how to get the selection and to link with my controller to output that result.

Comment: you can make use of the service even if it is in single directives right

Comment: Yes true....but for communication between two controllers I just wrote the service and tried to make use of that

Comment: you can use two controllers within a single directive right

Comment: yes when i tried two controllers in a single directive some error poped up...my mistake ...

Comment: so if two controllers in a single directive is possible, then you can use a single directive right, apart from that is there any other issues which you stick up with the two directives

Comment: No the isssue now is i m not getting the radio button selected value from the enterd data after submitting form.If I get I can compare that with the filter gender .hope i wll get some idea from ur plunker. lemme check

Comment: in that plunker i have done that, you can see there how i gets all the values....but the issue is that you have defines two directives so things will be a little difficult....

Comment: the filter is not working in tht plunker...i m struck with that part....it prints all the data  when we click the filter criteria...

Comment: i told you know that there you are using two directive, the datas for filtering is receiving on one directive and should be passed to another....if it is a single filter can be easily one and the view can be refreshed

Comment: you have to do some changes in the directive to make that fitering possible, also i think a table view is good for this, like a grid, share your thoughts

Comment: Now the data from the json is not working...I mean while giving in the if condition...  if($scope.details[i].sex===$scope.user.sex1)...the first part is not correct...the second part is working.   details is my array

Comment: its not showing error but its not working.....its in formcontroller.js if condition.....http://plnkr.co/edit/FwtaZTTyBFPZL1w1osJx?p=preview

Comment: will post the plunker again

Comment: In the plunker you can see a Fork option click that, and that will generate a new pluker for the updates, give me that

Comment: can u plz check the plunker...http://plnkr.co/edit/g3rdEL21e87JCUUAmT9e?p=preview.....i updated...the issue now is the filter is displaying only in the console....can u plz check out tht?...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your jsfiddle but here is a quick example of how you do it:

```
<div class="radio" data-ng-repeat="detail in details">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" data-ng-model="$parent.ngModel" name="ngModel" value="{{detail.id}}" required />
        {{detail.title}}
    </label>
</div>
```

in your controller just use `$scope.ngModel` and you will get the result.

Comment: I am getting the value of radio button in the form code. I am asking about the radio buttons which i need to put in the output form file for filtering data based on gender selection. if selected value print the data with that gender only.